# Calculating modular inverses with limited multiplication

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

**Question**

Given $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k \in \mathbb{Z}_n^\ast$, I want to compute $\alpha_1^{-1},\dots,\alpha_k^{-1}$ by computing only one multiplicative inverse and less than $3k$ multiplications modulo $n$.

**Current Idea**

Perform the multiplications to compute
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= a_1 \\
A_2 &= a_1a_2 \\
&\vdots \\
A_k &= a_1\cdots a_k \\
A_k' &= a_k \\
A_{k-1}' &= a_ka_{k-1} \\
&\vdots\\
A_{2}'&=a_k\cdots a_2.
\end{align*}
Since the previously computed value can be used in the multiplication for the next one, only one multiplication is used for each of the above values at most. So the total multiplications used to compute these initial values is $(k-1)+(k-2)=2k-3$.

Compute $A_k^{-1} = (a_1\cdots a_k)^{-1} \mod n$ using the Extended Euclidean algorithm.

Then  $\alpha_1^{-1},\dots,\alpha_k^{-1}$ can be computed by taking
\begin{align*}
A_{k-1}A_k^{-1} &\equiv a_k^{-1}\\
A_{k-2}A_k^{-1}A_{k}' &\equiv a_{k-1}^{-1}\\
&\vdots\\
A_{1}A_k^{-1}A_{3}' &\equiv a_{2}^{-1}\\
A_k^{-1}A_{2}' &\equiv a_{1}^{-1}
\end{align*}
This however uses $2$ multiplication for each inverse except the first and last which only take one, so $2k-2$ multiplications. This totals to $4k-5$ multiplications, so I am using $k$ more multiplications than permitted. I am not sure how to remove $k$ multiplications from the total as this is the best method I have thought of. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can improve this?

Comment: Hint: Henri Cohen, A course in computational algebraic number theory. In Algorithm 10.3.4 (Parallel Inverse Modulo N) he gives a method which needs 1 Extended Euclid, plus $3k-3$ multiplications modulo $n$.

Comment: Another hint (because edit time has elapsed): Brent/Zimmermann describe a similar algorithm in Algorithm 2.11 (MultipleInversion) of Modern Computer Arithmetic (http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pub/pub226.html)

Comment: Wow the algorithms shown in Cohen does what I have shown but more efficiently; I was trying to think of a way to get all the inverses without using the $A_i'$, and did not think to multiply the $A_k^{-1}$ by an $\alpha_i$ every step... was close =/

Comment: @gammatester If you post your hint as an answer, I would like to accept that as the answer to this question.

Comment: Sorry, I was off-line during weekend, I will submit the answer immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Algorithm 10.3.4 (Parallel Inverse Modulo N) of his book *A course in computational algebraic number theory*, Henri Cohen gives a method (first noticed by P. Montgomery), which needs 1 Extended Euclid, plus $3k−3$ multiplications modulo $N$.